# data retrieving not getting properly

Tags: php, cakephp

```
if(isset($id)){


        $groups=$this->User->findByuser_group_id($id);
        $this->set('groups', $groups);

    }
```

This is code amn using to get database details from user by filtering user_group_id but here i am getting only only one value as per the user_group_id but in db am having morethen 5 users

Comment: Which Framework you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$groups=$this->User->findAllByuser_group_id($id);
        $this->set('groups', $groups);
```

Change find to findAll

Answer (score 0):

### Call find

Magic finders are sometimes useful but if you avoid them you'll find your code is easier to read, and more obvious how to modify.

To get *one* record:

```
$one = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'user_group_id' => $id
    )
));
```

To get *five* records:

```
$many = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'user_group_id' => $id
    ),
    'limit' => 5
));
```

The [find method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) is very flexible/versatile - check the docs for more ways to use it.